# What is the equivalent of boost::variant in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, boost, unions, variant, boost-variant

I am looking for an alternative to C-style union. boost::variant is one such option. Is there anything in std C++ ?

```
union {
   int i;
   double d;
}
```

Comment: There is not, but Boost.Variant is extremely likely to be in TR2.

Comment: Sadly, most of boost has no `std` equivalent yet.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using Boost. The whole point of C++ is that it lets you write libraries that do useful things. It doesn't try to provide everything out of the box, but rather, it gives you the tools to *make* everything you need. Use Boost.

Comment: Please note that `boost::variant` is a header-only library, so you don't need to worry about building/linking the Boost library if you're only using `boost::variant`. Just make sure the path to boost header files is included in your project/IDE/makefile.

Comment: @ildjarn: Was Boost.Variant proposed to the committee? I don't recall seeing the paper in the most recent mailing.

Comment: @Nicol : Not yet, but [Beman said not to worry about it](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/02/190619.php). :-P

Comment: @ildjarn That sounds overly optimistic. If I recall correctly, at least `boost::optional` has been submitted once before and nothing came of it.

Comment: A bit of a necro-post, but now that C++ has unrestricted unions, would `boost::variant` even be necessary?

Comment: @EvanTeran - Unrestricted unions may make it easier to implement a variant type, but they are not a substitute for them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As several commenters said: No, there is no Boost Variant-alike in standard C++.  Maybe in a few years there will be, but why wait--use Boost Variant today!

---

*Edit (four years later, 2016):* In C++17 there will be `std::variant`.  Similar but not identical to `boost::variant`.  So when your compiler supports C++17, you will have a solution in the standard library.

Comment: How does this qualify as an answer? This is a comment.

Comment: This answer will soon be outdated indeed. C++17 will include `std::variant`, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: @TimZaman: Thanks for the reminder.  I added an edit to note C++17 support.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I would be glad if you could have a look at a question I just asked following this answer of yours: [What are the differences between std::variant and boost::variant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201371/what-are-the-differences-between-stdvariant-and-boostvariant?noredirect=1&lq=1])

Answer (score 10):

A few years passed: Now [a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4542.pdf) is on the way. Possibly `boost::variant` will make it into C++17! Until then we will have to live with `boost::variant` which is still awesome. Note that there will be some changes in the details in `std::variant`.

**UPDATE:** The proposal made it. `std::variant` will be part of the new C++17 standard. Here's the [June 2016 meeting report by Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2016/06/30/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-oulu/). There he confirms it.

Comment: Can you list some of these changes?

Comment: The changes are still subject to change. ;) Some changes are controversial. Also it is rather not on the surface but there are some complicated design decisions. In order to not complicate the answer unnecessarily, I chose to be concise and to the point. Some of the issues can be found in the link to the proposal in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`std::variant` is now officially going to be a part of the C++17 standard library! https://herbsutter.com/2016/06/30/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-oulu/