# Why are there two variant class implementations in Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, boost-variant2

Boost seems to have two implementations of a variant class template:

- [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html)
- [`boost::variant2`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/variant2/doc/html/variant2.html)

It is rare (though not unheard of) for Boost two include two takes on the same concept. Why has this happened for variants? How do these variants differ?

Answer (score 6):

The first kind of variant class template, `boost::variant`, predates C++17's `std::variant`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40201371/1593077) for its comparison to `std::variant`. Mainly, the difference regards what to do when an exception is thrown on construction of a value within the variant.

The `std::variant` choice is to allow a valueless state; the `boost::variant` choice is to construct the new object on the heap, not in-place, and store a pointer to that location.

`boost::variant2` is a later addition, which, on the one hand, wishes to adhere to the C++17 API, but on the other hand is an expression of dissatisfaction with its choice on this matter.

`boost::variant2` chooses a third option, different than both previous implementations: double-buffering. It takes up twice the size of the problematic type; constructs a new value in the unused half, and once the construction succeeds - destroys the old value in the other half. If all types are nothrow-constructible, this is not necessary and `boost::variant2` will not actually have the double buffer.

This choice means that `boost::variant2` can *never be valueless*; and indeed, its documentation title emphasizes this fact.