Substituting `std::holds_alternative` in C++14 with mapbox variant
I'm currently downporting C++17 code to C++14. Since C++14 doesn't have variant I'm using the variant implementation by mapbox which is available here. Basically, substituting variant using mapbox::util::variant works fine but apparently mapbox's implementation of variant doesn't have an equivalent for std::holds_alternative which is unavailable in C++14. So I don't know how to port the following code to C++14:
bool isType() const
{
    return std::holds_alternative<SheetType>(m_sheet);
}

m_sheet is declared like this:
mapbox::util::variant<XLWorksheet, XLChartsheet> m_sheet;

Does anybody have an idea how to do what std::holds_alternative does in C++14 with mapbox's variant implementation? Thanks!

Any specific reason you didn't choose boost::variant?

I'm not very familiar with C++ but isn't boost some sort of huge library with lots of dependencies? I was looking for something lightweight that's just a header or two.

@Andreas: Boost is a collection of libraries. And most of the dependencies are boost-internal, so downloading all of boost solves that. In addition, Boost also is by far the most common source for new C++ standard libraries; std::variant is directly derived from boost::variant. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201371/what-are-the-differences-between-stdvariant-and-boostvariant

There's a mapbox::util::variant::is member template. In non-template code you'd replace
return std::holds_alternative<SheetType>(m_sheet);

by
return m_sheet.is<SheetType>();

Whereas in templates, if SheetType is dependent, then you'd need
return m_sheet.template is<SheetType>();

Which is why std::holds_alteantive, std::get, and co. are implemented as free functions. If need be, it's not hard to wrap is either:
template<typename Alt, typename ...Vars>
bool mapbox_holds_alternative(mapbox::util::variant<Vars...> const& v) {
    return v.template is<Alt>();
}

